# twitter API replies to tweets

Tags: api, twitter, endpoint

Twitter have updated! Aarrgghhhhh.

My favorite related_results endpoint has gone down, as far as I can tell, last night when the upgrade took place:

https://api.twitter.com/1/related_results/show/172019363942117377.json?include_entities=1

This was the endpoint that would return any tweets that were part of a conversation i.e. the replies to a specific tweet.  This probably makes it clearer: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11292

I'll be searching to find a another one ASAP, if I do, I'll post it here.  But if anyone knows of a similar one (that works with the upgraded API), and could post it, that'd be AMAZING!!!!

Cheers,
Sam

(In the mean time, my stuff is broken.  Feel free to post any patronizing comments about how stupid I was to use unofficial parts of the API/ didn't listen when I was told to migrate etc.)

Comment: Just change endpoint version to `1.1` (but you'll have to authenticate for that)

Comment: There is no version 1.1 of this API working today.